# what's different between SetDefaultCloseOperation parameters?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

what is different between **Dispose_On_Close** and **Exit_On_Close** in **setDefaultCloseOperation** method in **JFrame** class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As their name implies, dispose on close disposes the window when it's closed while exit on close exits the JVM on window close. If the window is a JFrame and if it is the last window showing and if there are no non-daemon threads running, they'll both do the same thing -- exit the jvm. Per the API:

> When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate.

I generally prefer to use dispose on close because of this.

Answer (score 3):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` ends the complete thread by calling `System.exit(0)`. `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` only closes the jframe, the thread runs on until it's terminated by something else. You can test this with a program that has 2 JFrames with the 2 different close operations. If you close the one with `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` both Frames will close, but if you close the one with `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` set as close operation, only this one will disappear and the other one will stay.